# Device wise font change but not apply font family and type - how to add font type and font family is ClashGrotesk

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, fonts

This is device wise font change code if open iPad then font size is big and if open small device like iPhone SE, 8, 6 elc, then font size is small according small device

This code is perfectly run but in this code add font type added.

How can I add it?

```
extension UIFont {

//    static func setFont(type: fontType = .clashGroteskSemibold, size: CGFloat = UIFont.systemFontSize) -> UIFont {
//        return UIFont(name: type.rawValue, size: size.dp) ?? UIFont()
//    }

    class func appFont(
        ofSize size : CGFloat = UIFont.systemFontSize,
        weight : Weight = .semibold
    ) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size.dp, weight: weight)
    }
}
extension CGFloat {
    var dp: CGFloat {
        
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let device = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom
        
        if (device == .phone) {
            if (width <= 375) {
                // iPhone(SEGen2 6, 6s, 7, 8, X, Xs, 11pro, 12mini, 13mini)
                return self * 0.60
            } else if (width <= 414) {
                // iPhone(6+, 6s+, 7+, 8+, XsMax, XR, 11, 11proMax, 12, 12pro, 13, 13pro)
                return self
            }
        }
        else if (device == .pad) {
            if (width <= 1024) {
                // ipad(miniGen6, )
                return self * 2.0
            }
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

call func code

```
cell.stepsLabel.font = UIFont.appFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .semibold)
```

I have add custome font and font type but not warking
I have face error is optional valur unrapped this type of error are faced.

```
extension UIFont {
    public enum fontType: String {
        case clashGroteskSemibold = "ClashGrotesk-Semibold"
        case clashGroteskRegular = "ClashGrotesk-Regular"
        case clashGroteskMedium = "ClashGrotesk-Medium"
        case clashGroteskLight = "ClashGrotesk-Light"
        case clashGroteskExtralight = "ClashGrotesk-Extralight"
        case clashGroteskBold = "ClashGrotesk-Bold"
    }
    
    class func appFont(
        type: fontType = .clashGroteskSemibold,
        ofSize size : CGFloat = UIFont.systemFontSize
    ) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: type.rawValue, size: size.dp)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use custom font, make sure register font in **info.plist** under **"Fonts provided by application"** property.
*Note: Font name should be same as filename with file extension.*

Register Custom Font:

[image: Register Custom Font]

And also ensure that the custom font is available in your app's target. You can confirm from File Inspector for custom font file in **Target Membership**. For Reference, look into attached image.

Font Target:

[image: Font Target]

To avoid nil value errors, use this code in UIFont extension:

```
enum FontType: String {
    case clashGroteskBold = "ClashGrotesk-Bold"
    case clashGroteskSemibold = "ClashGrotesk-Semibold"
    case clashGroteskRegular = "ClashGrotesk-Regular"
    case clashGroteskMedium = "ClashGrotesk-Medium"
    case clashGroteskLight = "ClashGrotesk-Light"
    case clashGroteskExtralight = "ClashGrotesk-Extralight"
}

class func appFont(type: FontType = .clashGroteskSemibold, ofSize size : CGFloat = UIFont.systemFontSize) -> UIFont {
    
    guard let font = UIFont(name: type.rawValue, size: size.dp) else {
        return self.systemFont(ofSize: size.dp)
    }
    return font
}
```